# How do I know through code if I can scroll to one side or the other in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uiscrollview

I need to include tooltip images. If it is possible to scroll down, I include the bottom tooltip. If it is possible to scroll up, I include the top tooltip. If I can scroll up and down, I turn on both.

I have been puzzling over this problem for the second day and have not found anything like this on the Internet. I will be very grateful if you can help me.

```
public class ScrollHint : MonoBehaviour
{
        [SerializeField] private GameObject _topHint;
        [SerializeField] private GameObject _bottomHint;
        
        [Header("")]
        [SerializeField] private ScrollRect _scrollRect;
        
        private void OnEnable()
        {
                _scrollRect.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnUpdateValueScrollRect);
                if (_scrollRect.normalizedPosition.y > 0f) _bottomHint.Enable();
        }
        
        private void OnUpdateValueScrollRect(Vector2 vector)
        {
                UpdateScrollTips();
                BorderCheck(vector.y);
        }
        
        
        private void UpdateScrollTips()
        {
                if (_scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition < 1f && _topHint.activeSelf == false)
                        _topHint.Enable();
                if (_scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition > 0f && _bottomHint.activeSelf == false)
                        _bottomHint.Enable();
        }
        
        private void BorderCheck(float value)
        {
                if (value <= 0f && _bottomHint.activeSelf) _bottomHint.Disable();
                if (value >= 1f && _topHint.activeSelf) _topHint.Disable();
        }
}
```

Don't look at the quality of the code, I change it all the time, trying to make it work. The behavior is almost correct, but, it shows incorrectly when the object is enabled and if you can't scroll, it also shows that you can scroll up or down.

Answer (score 0):

My sample code is in down.
If you have any question, Knock me.

```html
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

public class DebugRuntimeConsole : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A struct to hold all the info about a debug message.
    /// </summary>
    private struct DebugMessage
    {
        /// <summary> The condition text. </summary>
        public string Condition { get; set; }
        /// <summary> The stack trace. </summary>
        public string StackTrace { get; set; }
        /// <summary> The type of the log. </summary>
        public LogType Type { get; set; }

        public DebugMessage(string condition, string stackTrace, LogType type)
        {
            Condition = condition;
            StackTrace = stackTrace;
            Type = type;
        }
    }

    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("Determines if the console should be enabled.")]
    private bool m_EnableConsole = false;
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("The key to press to toggle the visibility of the console.")]
    private KeyCode m_ToggleKey = KeyCode.F8;
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("Determines if timestamps should be added to the log message.")]
    private bool m_ShowTimestamps = true;
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("Determines if the game object should be kept through scenes.")]
    private bool m_DontDestroyOnLoad = true;
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("Determines if the logs can be exported into a text file.")]
    private bool m_CanExportLogs = true;
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("An optional IMGUI skin.")]
    private GUISkin m_GUISkin;

    [Header("Color Settings")]
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("The color for the basic log message.")]
    private Color m_LogColor = Color.white;
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("The color for warning messages.")]
    private Color m_WarningColor = Color.yellow;
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("The color for error messages.")]
    private Color m_ErrorColor = Color.red;
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("The color for exception messages.")]
    private Color m_ExceptionColor = Color.red;
    [SerializeField]
    [Tooltip("The color for assert messages.")]
    private Color m_AssertColor = Color.red;

    // The entry to be expanded. -1 means no entry.
    private int m_ExpandedEntry = -1;

    // Determines if the console should be shown.
    private bool m_Show;

    // The Vector2 for the scroll bar.
    private Vector2 m_Scroll;

    // All the messages.
    private List<DebugMessage> m_Messages = new List<DebugMessage>();

    void Start()
    {
        // If Dont Destroy On Load is marked, mark the game object as such.
        if (m_DontDestroyOnLoad)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

            // If it can find another debug console, destroy the object current game object.
            DebugRuntimeConsole otherConsole = FindObjectOfType<DebugRuntimeConsole>();
            if (otherConsole != null && otherConsole.transform != this.transform)
                Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Subscribe to the log message received event.
        Application.logMessageReceived += OnGetLogMessage;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // Unsubscribe to the log message received event.
        Application.logMessageReceived -= OnGetLogMessage;
    }

    private void OnGetLogMessage(string condition, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        // If Show Timestamps is checked, add a timestamp with the current hour, minute and second.
        if (m_ShowTimestamps)
        {
            string originalCondition = condition;
            condition = "[" + System.DateTime.Now.Hour + ":" + System.DateTime.Now.Minute + ":" + System.DateTime.Now.Second + "] " + originalCondition;
        }

        // Trim the condition and stack trace.
        condition = condition.Trim();
        stackTrace = stackTrace.Trim();

        // Add the message.
        m_Messages.Add(new DebugMessage(condition, stackTrace, type));
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Show when toggle key is pressed and console is enabled.
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(m_ToggleKey) && m_EnableConsole)
        {
            m_Show = !m_Show;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        // Only run if show and enable console is enabled.
        if (m_Show && m_EnableConsole)
        {
            // If there's a skin, apply it.
            if (m_GUISkin != null)
                GUI.skin = m_GUISkin;

            // Begin an area.
            GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, 300), GUI.skin.box);
            // Begin the scroll area.
            m_Scroll = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(m_Scroll);

            // Loop through every message.
            for (int i = 0; i < m_Messages.Count; i++)
            {
                // Create a new label style and base it on the original label.
                GUIStyle labelStyle = GUI.skin.label;
                // Create a entry color field.
                Color entryColor = Color.magenta;
                // Get the entry color based on the message type.
                switch (m_Messages[i].Type)
                {
                    case LogType.Error:
                        entryColor = m_ErrorColor;
                        break;
                    case LogType.Assert:
                        entryColor = m_AssertColor;
                        break;
                    case LogType.Warning:
                        entryColor = m_WarningColor;
                        break;
                    case LogType.Log:
                        entryColor = m_LogColor;
                        break;
                    case LogType.Exception:
                        entryColor = m_ExceptionColor;
                        break;
                }
                // Set the text color to the entry color.
                labelStyle.normal.textColor = entryColor;

                // Create a button that looks like a label.
                if (GUILayout.Button(m_Messages[i].Condition, labelStyle))
                {
                    // When clicked, if the selected entry is the same as this message, close the entry.
                    // Else set the selected entry to thie message entry.
                    if (m_ExpandedEntry == i)
                        m_ExpandedEntry = -1;
                    else
                        m_ExpandedEntry = i;
                }

                // If the expanded entry is this message, show the stack trace.
                if (m_ExpandedEntry == i)
                {
                    // Create a new box style based on the GUI skin box.
                    GUIStyle boxStyle = GUI.skin.box;
                    // Set the text alignment.
                    boxStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
                    // Set the text color to the same color as the entry color.
                    boxStyle.normal.textColor = entryColor;
                    // Show it as a box.
                    GUILayout.Box(m_Messages[i].StackTrace, boxStyle);
                }
            }

            // End the scroll view.
            GUILayout.EndScrollView();

            // If Can Export Logs is checked, show the export button.
            if (m_CanExportLogs)
            {
                // When click, do the export logs function.
                if (GUILayout.Button("Export Logs"))
                {
                    ExportLogs();
                }
            }

            // And lastly end the area.
            GUILayout.EndArea();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exports all logs to Application.dataPath/logs
    /// </summary>
    public void ExportLogs()
    {
        // If Can Export Logs is unchecked, stop here.
        if (!m_CanExportLogs)
            return;

        // Create a new string builder.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Loop through all the messages.
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Messages.Count; i++)
        {
            // Add the message type to the line.
            switch (m_Messages[i].Type)
            {
                case LogType.Error:
                    sb.Append("[ERROR] ");
                    break;
                case LogType.Assert:
                    sb.Append("[ASSERT] ");
                    break;
                case LogType.Warning:
                    sb.Append("[WARNING] ");
                    break;
                case LogType.Log:
                    sb.Append("[LOG] ");
                    break;
                case LogType.Exception:
                    sb.Append("[EXCEPTION] ");
                    break;
                default:
                    sb.Append("[UNKNOWN TYPE] ");
                    break;
            }

            // Append the condition.
            sb.Append(m_Messages[i].Condition);
            // Start a new line.
            sb.AppendLine();
            // Add the stack trace.
            sb.AppendLine(m_Messages[i].StackTrace);
            // Add a new empty line.
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        // Make sure the output directory exists.
        if (!Directory.Exists(Application.dataPath + "/output_logs/"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.dataPath + "/output_logs/");

        // Create the file name and then the file.
        System.DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2} {3}-{4}-{5}.txt", now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/output_logs/" + fileName, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```